# Custom CSS Scrollbar not responding on far right pixel 0

Tags: css, electron, webkit, scrollbar

When cursor is dragged far right, to the zeroth pixel, custom scrollbar doesn't respond, instead text is selected as if dragging anywhere inside body.

Put a browser in full screen or maximize, so you know you're not dragging on the window resize border. (On Mac, scroll a bit so the OS scrollbar appears.)

- Not just on my project, take a look at a random [CSS-Tricks page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
- Default OS scrollbar works as expected (like here on Stackoverflow), custom one doesn't (like on CSS-Tricks).
- To reproduce in a project, simply declare `::-webkit-scrollbar { ... }`, eg. give a it a width and a background color. And yes, `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` is end to end, that's not the issue I believe.
- Happens on Chrome and Electron, don't know about Firefox.
- *This is important because it's the last pixel, i.e. the "drag far to the right" mouse action. It's not just a single pixel issue!*

Anyone know an elegant solution? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, quite unexpected behavior.

Set the body, main container or whatever is your main scroll to `position: fixed` or `absolute`, so you have access to `right` property.

Set `right: -1px;`